# How can I divert my data to a Linux VPN and then forward it to a destination?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, games, vpn

I live at place A.
I need to connect to place C.
Direct connection A->C (300ms, it was 60 ms previously but some ISP routing issues atm)

I have an Ubuntu server hosted at Point B.
A->B I get 20ms.
B->C I get 50ms.
Is there any way like setting a VPN on machine B so that I can reroute my traffic from A to C through B?
If yes, how?
I need A->B->C connection.
(Sorry if I didn't put up the problem properly, I am not a native English speaker)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what a VPN is. However, it looks like you want to do this as a general solution to a latency problem, which a VPN is not. A VPN connection will likely increase latency, due to the encryption and decryption of traffic as it goes through the VPN.

Comment: I live in Mumbai, India (Place A). Place C is Singapore. There is a direct submarine cable between Chennai(India) (which is located on East Coast of India) to SG but it got damaged in December. My ISP rerouted all the traffic to SG through USA. Also, as stated above, I used to get 60-70 ms previously. So I guess a VPN set up on machine B will solve my problem. I am not a networking/computer expert, just need proper guidelines to follow :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you need to look into OpenVPN.  You install an OpenVPN server on machine B (I suggest adding DNSMasq on machine B too, so that all DNS requests are also sent to the DNS used by machine B).  The OpenVPN can push routes to the clients, with the `push-route` option.  In your case that would then be the IP address (or IP range) of machine C.

Finally you set up the client on machine A, so it connects to machine B.  It then receives the routing to C and any connection to C will then go over B.

I admit, it would be better if I gave you a full How-To on how to actually setup OpenVPN, but it is a rather complex endeavour.  There are many good tutorials though.

Alternatively, would ssh tunneling work for you?  That's much easier than actually setting up a full blown VPN.  It would be as easy as executing this:
`ssh -L 8080:machine-c:80 youruser@machine-B` on Machine A.  What this does, is open up port 8080 on localhost Machine A, and tunnels it over Machine B to Machine C on port 80.  As such, if you point your browser (port 80 is http, so browser) to `http://localhost:80`, you will get the (default) content of Machine C.

This works for other ports too.

Finally, you can run on Machine A, the command `ssh -D 8080 youruser@machine-B`.  This way you create a SOCKS proxy on your localhosts, that will exit at machine-B.  Set your browsers SOCKS settings to `localhost:8080` and any connection make will be routed over machine-B.

Theoretically any SOCKS capable software can then use that proxy, but your browser can do that, so that's why I gave it as an example.

It really depends a bit on the real use case you have, on what is really the best choice.

Comment: Thank you for the brief answer. I am running windows 10 on machine A and Ubuntu on B. I use SSH to connect to B from A. Also, I only need to reroute the incoming/outgoing traffic on port 27015 on machine A (Windows). Any specific instructions/guides for that?

Comment: In that case, ssh tunneling will do.  Alas, I'm a full time Linux user, so my Windows knowledge is from memory.  I presume, you already use PuTTY.  PuTTY can do tunneling.  You need to define it somewhere in the configuration options.

Comment: This looks adequate:
http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html

Comment: That's a Steam port... Hmmm... Do keep in mind that ssh tunneling will only work for TCP connections....

Comment: Also, if that really is for steam, you'll have to force the Steam client to use localhost instead of whatever hostname it uses.  You can do that in the hosts file, but I assure you, that if this is for steam you'll have a lot of work to get this as expected.

I have run Steam over OpenVPN.  That's most likely the easiest path, especially if you redirect all traffic over the VPN.

Comment: "ssh tunneling will only work for TCP connections" Most of the packets used are UDP. I guess SSH won't be of any use here then :P

Comment: I tried using some free/trial VPN's but their routing also seems to be messed up. I guess I'll have to set up an OpenVPN server on machine B and connect machine A to B using OpenVPN. Will that work? I can use a full time VPN connection from A to B.

Comment: As I guessed.  Steam.  Next time just explain your problem directly, that stops people from guessing.

I have run the Steam client over OpenVPN.  That works just fine.  I would suggest you try OpenVPN.  Be warned: it is not for the faint of heart to set that up.  Easiest will be to set up a OpenVPN, that reroutes ALL traffic over the VPN.  Look for tutorials...

Comment: Yes, you can...  Still, you should complain to your ISP for their sucky routing. I just summarily overflew it, this should do... https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04 
Personally, I do it differently, but if it works, it works...

Comment: Good luck... This is not easy, and I have no time to do a full write up.

Comment: I guess this will get the job done. Thank you for the valuable time and answers!